# Checking if access token isnt expired

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have application which gives access token after authentication and I want to check if token is not expired

```
@JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    private String expires_in;

public boolean isNotExpired() {
        return ! Instant.now().isBefore(Instant.parse(expires_in));
    }
```

But after I run application I get errors:

```
JSON encoding error: Text '3600' could not be parsed at index 4; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Text '3600' could not be parsed at index 4 (through reference chain: com.Auth.AuthInfo["notExpired"])
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you keep the value of 3600 there instead of the actual date-time of the expiration?

It will easily solve your problem.
If you want to keep how long the token is valid you would also need the issue time of the token to check that the diff of `current time` - `issue time` is not greater than the value of a field like `validFor`.